# How to Get and Change Windows Credential Username and Password

Tags: c#, windows, credentials

I want to write a application in C# using WMI that can get and change Windows credential stored  in the Windows Credential Manager, as you see in the picture below:

[image: Windows Credential manager]

Answer (score 2):

[Ookii.Dialogs](http://www.ookii.org/software/dialogs/) contains a credential dialog, which calls into [CredUIPromptForCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375177%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) or [CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375178%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) as appropriate.

Edit: The Credentials API is detailed at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374731%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#credentials_management_ui_functions - but it could be tricky to implement from managed code. After CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials you would call [CredWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375187%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to save the credentials.

Comment: From what i understand, any of that just lets the user log in using their credentials.  I may be wrong but i don't believe there is anything in that api to be able to change credentials.

Comment: @Andy This has nothing to do with logging in. It's about storing credentials in the Windows 7 vault.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Misunderstood the original question since the pic wasn't visible.

I'm not sure if you can do what you want via WMI. However, I think it might be possible using the [DPAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx), but the documentation for that doesn't seem to make it very easy. However, there is an opensource project called [NCrypto](http://ncrypto.sourceforge.net/default.htm) that has a class called `UICredentialsHelper` which might show you how to do it, or at least how to get started.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Windows API to get a user's password. Passwords are not stored in Windows.  Instead Windows stores a one-way hashed version.

You can get the username using WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().  Alternatively you can get the logged in user name via the Environment.UserName property.

Although to change credentials..... good luck :)  Thats my best answer on that.  I don't think Microsoft would ever give us the ability to do that.

Comment: -1 : The poster is talking about Windows Credential Manager, which is used to store usernames & passwords. It does not store a hash but a machine encrypted password so it can be decrypted.

Answer (score 0):

[void]Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault,Windows.Security.Credentials,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
(new-object Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault).RetrieveAll() | % { $*.RetrievePassword(); $* }